# How can i export specific azure resources to an json file (arm template)

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-manager

how can i filter specific resources to export it (for my documentation or slt)?
If i want to export, portal or cli will always export the whole resources within a specific resource group. What if i only want virtual networks, or storage accounts?

Thanks in advance, Markus

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there's no way to filter the resources that are exported.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your resource and open the "Resource Explore, it will show you the JSON of that specific resource. Not all types of resources have this option though.
https://www.michaelcrump.net/azure-tips-and-tricks25/
[image]